# Appium: Not able to click the element

Tags: python, automation, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

When I tried to search a text using the Accessibility the test cases is passing, but when I tried to click that element it's throwing an error message as follows:

Code:

```
appname = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('FalconCabin')

appname.click()
```

[image]

Comment: Try explicit wait for element be able to receive click.

Comment: Also try printing self.driver.page_source before the error to know what exactly is on the page.

Comment: it says that the element is not visible, so add a Webdriver wait, before clicking it